# SVN post-commit does not execute

Tags: linux, apache, svn, post-commit

My post-commit is not executing. There are no errors logged in Apache. The post-commit file owner/permissions are apache:apache -rwxrwxrwx and the code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/svn update /home/MYWORKINGCOPY/public_html
```

The working directory owner is apache:apache. Lastly, executing the command from the post-commit file from the shell works properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hook executed under Apache and can't perform authorization in repo (tried to do it interacrively),

Comment: I added --username and --password to the post-commit command and it still doesn't execute on commit.

Comment: Also added --non-interactive, still doesn't execute.

Comment: Intercept stdout|stderr output and save to log